# svn commit local changes to another repo (no access to previous repo)

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I have the following situation:

- Working copy check out from SVNrepo1, made some local changes.
- SVNrepo1 became unavailable, so I can't commit
- I created another SVNrepo2
- I want to move the whole development, so I want to commit local changes, together with the whole Working copy to SVNrepo2

How do I do that? I use TortoiseSVN, but command line solutions are also OK.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Use the 'relocate' command, which basically tells your working copy that it should reference the new repo.

Then you can commit as before.

If you have a new, clean repo to commit into then you'll also have to add the filesd as they'll appear to be new ones to the new repo.

Comment: I receive an error:

---------------------------
TortoiseSVN
---------------------------
The repository at 'https://subversion.assembla.com/svn/****' has uuid
 'e74e6d1e-0e87-4949-945d-c3cffa99****', but the WC has
 'a09e2d3c-1222-43f2-910d-cef0a6c2****'
---------------------------

Comment: ok, so you have a brand new repo after all. In that case, the easist way is to checkout a new WC, copy the files across, and commit them. Or you can use setuuid on the new repo (its an admin command) to update the uuid to match the original, then you can relocate. I would use the checkout approach, easiest and safest.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I solved the problem the following way:

1. Exported the Working Copy to Backup folder using Export... option of TortoiseSVN
2. Cleared up the source directory
3. Checked out from the brand new SVNrepo2 to the source directory
4. Copied the files
5. Committed the changes